# Token in URL changes on click

Tags: authentication, php, csrf, token, url

Logging into OpenCart admin, I find a token in its URL:

```
http://localhost/opencart/admin/index.php?route=common/dashboard&token=xOHq2UzQ0YwKTubXgxNpGFySmAA9W90z
```

The synchronizer token pattern is implemented in OpenCart for security reasons, removing its functionality could leave store vulnerable to CSRF attacks.

I wanted something similar to the one above and tried this:

**index.php**

```
<?php

session_start();
$time = time();
$token = md5(uniqid(mt_rand($time), true));

$_SESSION['token']=$token;
?>

<html>
    <head>
    </head>

    <body>  
        <a href= "contact.php?token=<?php echo $_SESSION['token']; ?>">Contact</a>
    </body>
</html>
```

**contact.php**

```
<?php
session_start();

if($_SESSION['token']!=$_GET['token']) {
    echo 'hi';
} else {
    die('not valid');
}
?>
```

On clicking the link "contact" in the **index.php**, the token value changes and the contact page dies and says "not valid".

How do I correct this?

Comment: You don't really want to pass your token via GET if not necessary (GET requests shouldn't change server state, so they shouldn't need CSRF protection; if they do, rethink your approach). Tokens are sensitive data, and sensitive data should only be passed via POST, as it could leak otherwise (in server logs, browser histories, etc; and more importantly in this case: when sharing urls and in referers). It's also not good for usability, as it prevents bookmarks etc from working.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$_SESSION['token']!=$_GET['token']
```

**!= means is not equal.** So "hi" will be displayed when the values are not equal and it will die when it is equal and validation passes. Watch for that simple typographical errors next time!